# Eliminate repetitive try catch statement in async express route callbacks?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have an api written in Node JS with Express. All of my routes follow this pattern:

```
router.get("/my/url", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    // await code...
  }catch(error){
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({message: "Server Error"})
  }
});
```

This try catch is the same in all of my routes. What are some ways I can negate this, having it written in one place only, so my routes are more like:

```
router.get("/my/url", async (req, res) => {
  // await code...
});
```

Comment: The easiest way to achieve abstraction is using a wrapper function. Has always been true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout this package [`express-async-errors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors)

Import the package after `express`, and then you need to only define the error handler like this

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({message: "Server Error"})
});
```

Comment: Why does the error handler only work when it is added AFTER I mount my routes and not before I mount my routes?

Comment: because that's how express middlewares work, they are processed in order, and when an error happen it's sent to the next handler `next(err)` so to catch the error you must add the error handler as the last one.